# setup a vod for mp4 video files using nginx and rtmp

Tags: nginx, mp4, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I am using adobe captivate.
We are planning to provide live streaming of mp4 videos.
How do I set up live streaming of mp4 using nginx and rtmp?
Any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MP4 is not a streaming format. It is more or less impossible to have 'live' streaming mp4. You need a streaming container like flv or ts.

Comment: Even with a container like flv, I am not able to stream the video in captivate. Any advice on this. Thanks.